# Are there problems with strong retain issues with code such as this:

Tags: ios, swift

In the following code, is there a problem with the self in self.tableView.reloadData() being a strong reference, and should it be changed to be weak, or is it ok as it is?

```
class SomeViewController : UIViewController {
    fileprivate var notificationToken: NotificationToken?  = nil


...
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onNotification), name: NSNotification.Name(SomeNotification), object: nil)

        realmNotificationToken = blockedList.observe({ (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            switch changes
            {
            case .initial:
                self.tableView.reloadData() // Case 1
                break
...


    @objc func onNotification()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.tableView.reloadData() // Case 2
        }
    }
```

In both of these examples are there any problems with retain cycles due to the fact self is a strong reference, and it should change to weak?
In both instances, what is the life time of the two blocks within which self.tableView.reloadData() is being used? If the lifetime is ephemeral then there's no problems with using strong, are these blocks however long lived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 2 is a non escaping closure so there is no issue.

Case 1 is `@escaping` so you need to use a `weak` or `unowned` reference.  `@escaping` means you are passing the closure to something that may outlive the object that created the closure (ie you ViewController).  If you strongly capture `self` in the `@escaping` then your ViewController now lives for as long as the closure lives, and the closure lives until you cancel your subscription.  If you only cancel the subscription when the ViewController deintializes then you now have a cycle.  The closure can never be released because the subscription never dies and the ViewController can never die because the subscription never dies.

EDIT:
I should add you actually don't need self in either case; you can simply capture the tableview (if its implicitly unwrapped it will be desugared into a plain optional, which is fine):

```
realmNotificationToken = blockedList.observe({ [tableView] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
   switch changes {
   case .initial:
      tableView?.reloadData()
```